# Disable Printing in a PDF Viewer ActiveX control?

Tags: vb.net, pdf, activex

I'm using the Adobe Acrobat PDF Viewer ActiveX (AxAcroPDFLib.AxAcroPDF) control in one of my forms to display Controlled Document PDFs and my customer would like end users to not be able to print these documents. Is there anyway to disable printing through this control?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The PDF format supports permissions and "allow printing" is one of the permissions. If you can control the PDF generation of these controlled PDFs your best bet is to disable the allow print permission for users. You can also even run existing PDFs through a conversion process to add the necessary permissions with iText, ghostscript or something similar.
Besides, even if you are able to to disable the print button on the ActiveX viewer, if the user is clever enough to realize it is merely a PDF, they could just download the PDF and print it normally.

Answer (score 0):

There's a new PDF software that does this by default. You would have to save the document as .wwf rather than .pdf. If the document is already in PDF format you can re-save it in WWF format.

It's provided by the World Wildlife Foundation in an effort to reduce paper use. The end user does not need to have the software installed on their computer for it to work. You can download the software for both MAC or PC from the link below. Hope this helps!

http://www.saveaswwf.com/en/

Comment: This is really interesting, I'll probably use both of these methods, as there are some files we never want printed and some we want printed occasionally.